# Microsoft SQL select from X tables

Tags: sql-server

I need to select a row from all tables but without defining table names and amount of tables?
Something like `SELECT * FROM * WHERE id = 'test'`

Is this possible?

Comment: Not without writing some dynamic code to fetch all the table names first (and checking they have an `id` column).

Comment: No. You could do something with sp_MSforeachTable, cursors by querying sys.tables and building up dynamic SQL, etc. But there's no one command you can do that'll achieve this result.

Comment: Like [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-introduction-to-sp_msforeachtable-run-commands-iteratively-through-all-tables-in-a-database/)?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) if I am honest. What are you hoping to achieve with these rows from each table?

Answer (score 2):

You need to build up a dynamic query using system tables and execute it

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
'SELECT *
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + '
WHERE id = ''test'';'
      AS nvarchar(max)), '
'      )
    FROM sys.tables t
    WHERE t.object_id IN (
        SELECT c.object_id
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.name = 'id'
    )
);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```